# Move sails.js asests and .tmp folder and serve from new locations

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I'm new to Sails and due to an odd configuration requirement from the company I work for I need to (if I can) move the `assets` and `.tmp` folder outside of the normal sails structure but still make sails serve from the new locations.

The file structure look like this..

```
root
|
|__ client
|
|__ server(sails directory)
|
|__ assets/
|  |
|  |__ js/
|  |
|  |__ css/
|  |
|  |__ index.html
|
|
|__ .tmp/
```

so all the **grunt tasks** will be reconfigured to take advantage of the new structure, (copying files from new assets folder to new `.tmp` folder) but when you run sails lifts it serves the index.html from the new `.tmp` location

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the folder that Sails serves static files out of by setting the `sails.config.paths.public` property.  If you want it to apply to all environments, you could make a new config file (for example, `config/public.js`) and put it in there:

```
module.exports = {
  paths: {
    public: "../.tmp/public"
  }
}
```

Or, you could put it in your `.sailsrc` file.  Then, you'll need to change the paths in all of the `tasks/config` files to also point to `../.tmp/public` and `../assets`.

Comment: Fantastic, just the info I was looking for. Thanks!